# Como escrever um loop para ler um arquivo para um array de structs em C?

Tags: c, io

Olá. Tenho uma dúvida de como ler números de um determinado arquivo em c para colocar dentro do loop

O arquivo .txt terá os seguintes dados:

```
3
Joao Maria 
branco p
Marcio Guess
vermelho p
Maria Jose
branco p
2
Joao Losna
Vermelho G
Donald Trump
Branco P
0
```

Teria que ler o número 3, colocar dentro do laço de repetição, ler nome cor/tamanho guardar em variáveis.

Ler o próximo número que é o 2 colocar dentro do laço de repetição, ler os dados.

Até que o número seja 0 como no exemplo.

Parte do código em c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    char *nome[100];
    char cor[100];
    char tam[100];
} Camisetas;

int comparaNome(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const Camisetas *elemA = a;
    const Camisetas *elemB = b;
    int valor;
    if (elemA->cor[0] > elemB->cor[0])
        valor = 1;
    else if (elemA->cor[0] < elemB->cor[0])
        valor = -1;
    else if (elemA->tam[0] < elemB->tam[0])
        valor = 1;
    else if (elemA->tam[0] > elemB->tam[0])
        valor = -1;
    else if (elemA->nome[0] > elemB->nome[0])
        valor = 1;
    else if (elemA->nome[0] < elemB->nome[0])
        valor = -1;
    else
        valor = 0;
    return valor;
}

int main() {
    size_t len = 100; // valor arbitrário
    Camisetas pessoas[100];
    char c, *linha = malloc(len), *nome = malloc(len), *cor = malloc(len), *tam = malloc(len);
    int casos[100], i, j, k, C, aux, aux2;
    char url[] = "doc.txt";
    FILE *arq = fopen(url, "r");
    arq == NULL ? printf("Erro, nao foi possivel abrir o arquivo\n") : printf("Sucesso ao abrir o arquivo\n");

    //pegar os casos
    for (j = 0; j < 2 && !feof(arq); j++) {
        fscanf(arq, "%c", &C);
        casos[j] = atoi(&C);
        if (casos[j] != 0) {
            aux2 = casos[j];
        }
        aux = C * 2;
    }

    while (casos) {
        for (i = 0; i < aux && !feof(arq); i++) {
            getline(&pessoas[i].nome, &len, arq);//ou usar fscanf
            (fscanf(arq, "%s %s\n", &pessoas[i].cor, &pessoas[i].tam) != EOF);
        }

        qsort(pessoas, aux2, sizeof(Camisetas), comparaNome);
        for (k = 0; k < aux2; k++) {
            printf("%s %s %s", pessoas[k].cor, pessoas[k].tam, *pessoas[k].nome);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Olhe esses trechos: `else if (elemA->cor[0] cor[0])`, `else if (elemA->tam[0] tam[0])` e `else if (elemA->nome[0] nome[0])` - isso não compila.

Comment: Ignore meu comentário anterior. É que você tinha colocado o código dentro de tags `<pre><code>...</code></pre>`. Não faça isso. Ao invés de usar essas tags, idente com quatro espaços. Você pode usar o botão `{}` do editor após selecionar todo o seu código para fazer isso.

Comment: Por que na função `comparaNome` você olha apenas a primeira letra?

Comment: Por que você usa o asterisco em `char *nome[100];`, mas não em `char cor[100];` ou `char tam[100];`?

Comment: olá victor, sim a função comparaNome olha apenas a primeira letra para apos colocar em ordem alfabetica os nomes. dê uma olhada em <https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1258> e <http://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=260> os codigos são deste problema.

Comment: @carloscunha não pode andar assim a mudar a pergunta para uma nova, se tiver novas dúvidas crie uma nova com referência a esta. Senão as respostas podem perder a sua validade. Relembrando que aqui não é um fórum  e sim um site de Perguntas e Respostas. Cumprimentos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optei por refazer porque eu não consegui acompanhar muito bem o seu algoritmo. Algumas coisas não faziam muito sentido.

Com o seu conhecimento, creio que a leitura do código será auto-explicativa. Só a função 'main' já responde sua pergunta-- o resto é só para testar.

--O codigo foi alterado para adicionar a funcao de ordenacao das estruturas--

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define TAM_NOME 50
#define TAM_COR 20
#define MAXPORMALLOC 100//aumento do vetor por vez

typedef struct
{
    char* nome;
    char* cor;
    char* tamanho;
}td_Pessoa;

typedef struct
{
    td_Pessoa* pessoa;
    int pos;
    int loop;//controla o uso desnecessario do malloc
}td_Lista;

td_Lista* CriaLista();
td_Pessoa* CriaPessoa();
void IniciaLista(td_Lista*);
void AumentaTamanhoLista(td_Lista*);
void AdicionaPesoa(td_Lista*, td_Pessoa*);

void OrdenarPorCor(td_Lista* lista, char* cor);//FUNCAO NOVA
void TrocaPessoa(td_Pessoa* pessoa1, td_Pessoa* pessoa2); //FUNCAO NOVA

int main()
{
    FILE *arqEntrada, *arqSaida;

    int i;

    td_Pessoa* tmpPessoa = CriaPessoa();

    td_Lista *lista = CriaLista();
    IniciaLista(lista);

    int loop;

    if(arqEntrada = fopen("file.txt", "r"))
    {
        fscanf(arqEntrada, "%d", &loop);
        fgetc(arqEntrada); //para os \n
        do
        {
            for(i = 0; i < loop; i++)
            {
                fgets(tmpPessoa->nome, TAM_NOME, arqEntrada);
                fscanf(arqEntrada, "%s %s", tmpPessoa->cor, tmpPessoa->tamanho);
                fgetc(arqEntrada);

                if(lista->pos < (lista->loop * MAXPORMALLOC))
                    AdicionaPesoa(lista, tmpPessoa);
                else
                {
                    AumentaTamanhoLista(lista);
                    AdicionaPesoa(lista, tmpPessoa);
                }
            }
            fscanf(arqEntrada, "%d", &loop);
            fgetc(arqEntrada);
        }while(loop != 0);

        OrdenarPorCor(lista, "vermelho");//ORDENACAO

        //Mostra os valores armazenados no VETOR
        for(i = 0; i < lista->pos; i++)
            printf("%s%s %s\n", lista->pessoa[i].nome, lista->pessoa[i].cor, lista->pessoa[i].tamanho);

        //Coloca no arquivo de saida os valores do VETOR
        arqSaida = fopen("fpOUT.txt", "w+");
        for(i = 0; i < lista->pos; i++)
            fprintf(arqSaida, "%s%s %s\n", lista->pessoa[i].nome, lista->pessoa[i].cor, lista->pessoa[i].tamanho);

    }else
    {
        printf("O arquivo nao existe.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    free(lista);
    return 0;
}

void OrdenarPorCor(td_Lista* lista, char* cor)//FUNCAO NOVA
{
    int i, a;

    for(i = 0; i < lista->pos; i++)
        if(!strcmp(lista->pessoa[i].cor, cor))
            for(a = 0;; a++)
                if(strcmp(lista->pessoa[a].cor, cor))
                {
                    TrocaPessoa(&lista->pessoa[i], &lista->pessoa[a]);
                    break;
                }
}

void TrocaPessoa(td_Pessoa* pessoa1, td_Pessoa* pessoa2) //FUNCAO NOVA
{
    td_Pessoa* tmpPessoa = CriaPessoa();

    strcpy(tmpPessoa->nome, pessoa1->nome);
    strcpy(tmpPessoa->cor, pessoa1->cor);
    strcpy(tmpPessoa->tamanho, pessoa1->tamanho);

    strcpy(pessoa1->nome, pessoa2->nome);
    strcpy(pessoa1->cor, pessoa2->cor);
    strcpy(pessoa1->tamanho, pessoa2->tamanho);

    strcpy(pessoa2->nome, tmpPessoa->nome);
    strcpy(pessoa2->cor, tmpPessoa->cor);
    strcpy(pessoa2->tamanho, tmpPessoa->tamanho);

    free(tmpPessoa);
}

void AdicionaPesoa(td_Lista* lista, td_Pessoa* pessoa)
{
    strcpy(lista->pessoa[lista->pos].nome, pessoa->nome);  
    strcpy(lista->pessoa[lista->pos].cor, pessoa->cor);  
    strcpy(lista->pessoa[lista->pos].tamanho, pessoa->tamanho);  

    lista->pos++;
}

//essa parte de baixo é só para evitar o uso excessivo de MALLOC e REALLOC
td_Lista* CriaLista()
{
    td_Lista* res;

    res = (td_Lista*)malloc(sizeof(td_Lista));

    return res;
}

td_Pessoa* CriaPessoa()
{
    td_Pessoa* res = (td_Pessoa*)malloc(sizeof(td_Pessoa));

    res->nome   = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_NOME);
    res->cor    = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_COR);
    res->tamanho= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    return res;
}

void IniciaLista(td_Lista* lista)
{   
    int i;
    lista->loop = 1;
    lista->pos  = 0;

    lista->pessoa = (td_Pessoa*)malloc(sizeof(td_Pessoa) * lista->loop * MAXPORMALLOC);

    for(i = 0; i < MAXPORMALLOC; i++)
    {
        lista->pessoa[i].nome = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_NOME);
        lista->pessoa[i].cor= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_COR);
        lista->pessoa[i].tamanho = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
}

void AumentaTamanhoLista(td_Lista* lista)
{
    int i = lista->loop++ * MAXPORMALLOC;
    int tamanho = lista->loop * MAXPORMALLOC;

    lista->pessoa = (td_Pessoa*)realloc(lista, sizeof(td_Pessoa) * tamanho);

    for(; i < tamanho; i++)
    {
        lista->pessoa[i].nome = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_NOME);
        lista->pessoa[i].cor= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * TAM_COR);
        lista->pessoa[i].tamanho = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sugiro que traduza os nomes usados no seu código para português, já que a explicação de como ele funciona não está em nenhum outro lugar na resposta, e não devemos presumir aqui que os leitores entendem inglês.

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, vou alterar os nomes e editar o arquivo.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas, vou testar aqui e posto o retorno.

Comment: Olá deem uma olhada no novo código se puderem ajudar novamente agradeço muito.

Comment: pq vc optou por arvore binaria? no caso os valores ja estao sendo armazenados na estrutura "lista" só é necessario fazer uma ordenação, fiz duas funcoes novas ali para a ordenação, da uma olhada e avisa se ajudou.

Comment: No caso daquela arvore binaria ele me retorna a ordenação certa. o esses códigos são de um desafio retirado de:<https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1258> da uma olhada lá. no caso lá não precisaria fazer com arquivo mas eu quero fazer pelo arquivo. aguardo retorno