# Array em loop Infinito \ C

Tags: c, array, loop, for

Nesse exemplo a seguir, como eu faço para imprimir na tela todos os valores atribuidos a n durante o loop, apos sua finalização?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int n;
  
  for (;;)
  {
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    
    if (n == 7)
    {
      break; 
    }
    
    printf("Numero: %d\n",n);
  }
  
 
  getch();
  return(0);
}
```

**Eu tentei fazer assim:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main (void)
{
  int n[30];
  
  for (;;)
  {
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);
    
    if (n == 7)
    {
      break; 
    }
    
    for (xxxxxx)
    printf("Numero: %d\n", n[i]);
  }
  
 
  getch();
  return(0);
}
```

Nao sei o que por dentro de "for(xxxxxx)".

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Eu faria o seguinte

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n[30], i = 0, j;

    //lendo os valores  

    for( ; ; )
    {
        printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
        scanf("%d", &n[i]);
        if (n[i] == 7)
        {
           break; 
        }
        i++;
    }
    i++;

    //escrevendo após parar o loop

   for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
   {
       printf(" %d valor digitado: %d\n", j, n[j]);
   }
   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

Você usa um contador, no caso i, para ler e no fim ele vai guardar a posição do último valor digitado. Depois você quebra o loop de leitura e inicia um novo para escrever. Ele escreve os valores lidos contando as posições com um segundo contador que vai da primeira posição do array até a última que está guardada na variável i.

Comment: Muito obrigado, mano. Essa metodologia funciona direitinho no codigo que eu estava fazendo.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro seu loop não deveria ser infinito se está lendo valores para o array "n", que tem 30 posições, esse deveria ser o tamanho/duração/número de interações do seu loop.

Algumas considerações:

- Se declara um array com X posições, não faz sentido ler "parte" disso e sair no meio usando o `break`, seria melhor usar um array dinâmico, mas muito provavelmente pelo seu código e conhecimento que aparentemente tem, não é o que precisa. Para um array em `c`, use um array com tamanho definido, a não ser que seja extramente necessário fazer algo diferente;
- Para condições onde não se sabe **o número de interações** mas somente a condição de parada, é melhor usar por exemplo `while`. Então no primeiro código o `for (;;)` poderia ser `while (n != 7)`, para exemplificar;
- Respondendo a sua pergunta, pra listar os valores basta repetir o mesmo loop a seguir e mostrar os valores. Isso a título de exercício, pois se quiser simplesmente mostrar, pode ser no mesmo loop;

Vamos assumir que o valor 30, que tem no seu condicional seja o limite do seu loop, ou seja, que queira entrar com 30 valores, poderia fazer assim (respondendo à sua pergunta *"Nao sei o que por dentro de "for(xxxxxx)"*:

```
int totalDeNumeros = 30;
int n[totalDeNumeros];

for (int i=0;i< totalDeNumeros;i++)
{
    printf("Digite um numero inteiro: ");
    scanf("%d", &n[i]);
}

printf("Numeros digitados:\n");
for (int i=0;i< totalDeNumeros;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",n[i]);
}
```

Sobre um array dinâmico, tem uma outra pergunta relacionad com exemplo de código para perceber que é bem mais complexo de implementar: [Como escrever um loop para ler um arquivo para um array de structs em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165746/como-escrever-um-loop-para-ler-um-arquivo-para-um-array-de-structs-em-c)